# Using icacls to set permissions of a folder to inherit recursively

Tags: windows, icacls

I want to set a specific folder with specific rights to inherit all rights of it's parent folder. I know I should use `icacls`.

My folders look like this:

```
- mp
  - build (set this one to inherit from mp)
```

Answer (score 42):

Like this:

```
icacls "build\*" /q /c /t /reset
```

The secret was:

```
/reset - Replaces ACLs with default inherited ACLs for all matching files.
/t     - Performs the operation on all specified files in the current directory and its subdirectories.
```

Read more at [Microsoft Technet icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx)

Comment: I was having no luck and getting "invalid parameter" using /grant switch with (I) flag, but /reset worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to miss the reset option in the help.  As /T is being used for recursion, I don't think \\* is needed in the path.

Comment: `\*` is definitely needed if you want to reset just child folders and files, not the build folder itself.  Otherwise the build folder reverts to its parent's inheritance settings

Comment: This isn't "recursive"; it only affects immediate children. Anyone know a recursive solution?