# Powershell add administrator access to all files and folders under specific folder

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs, icacls

There are [a bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327776/using-icacls-to-set-permissions-of-a-folder-to-inherit-recursively) of [similar posts](https://superuser.com/questions/1668644/icacls-on-windows-server-19-doesnt-seem-to-work) to this, but [none of them](https://serverfault.com/questions/516324/unable-to-assign-group-permissions-with-icacls-on-windows-server-2012) seem to have the same issue that I have:

I'm trying to automate a script in Powershell that utilises both `icacls` and `takeown` to add an administrator group with Full Control to everything under that folder. This is an environment with about 150 TB of data, and this needs to run on thousands of folders so using the GUI is not an option.

**Goal:** Add Domain Admins (or any other domain group) with Full Control for all objects/containers under a specific folder.

Here's the code so far:

```
$Permission = "(OI)(CI)F"
$Username = "Domain Admins"
$GrantString = $Username + ":" + $Permission

foreach ($Folder in $FoldersToFix) {
    try {
        icacls ""$Folder"" /C /Q /grant ""$GrantString"" /T
        Write-ToMyLog "Success: $Folder"
    }
    catch {
        Write-ToMyLog "Warning: failed to grant permission on folder $Folder (error was: $(($_.Exception -split ":")[-1].Trim())). Trying to take ownership first..."
        try {
            takeown /F ""$Folder""
        }
        catch {
            Write-ToMyLog "Failed to take ownership for folder $Folder, error message was: $_"
            continue
        }
        try {
            icacls ""$Folder"" /C /Q /grant ""$GrantString"" /T
        }
        catch {
            Write-ToMyLog "Failed to update permissions for folder $Folder, error message was: $_"
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Problem I have is that the first `icacls` command only works on the topmost folder, it doesn't propagate to the subfolders unless I already have permission there. Both `/T` that's supposed to make it recursive, or just using `/reset` instead of `/grant` fail with Access Denied. If I take ownership first using `takeown` it seems to work better, but even that doesn't fully propagate. For example, let's say that I have the following structure without any permissions or ownership anywhere:

```
\\Server\Share\Folder
\\Server\Share\Folder\Subfolder
\\Server\Share\Folder\Subfolder\Leaf
```

The only way that I've found to make this work is if I run `takeown /F "\\Server\Share\Folder" /A /R /D Y` as anything else will either fail with an access denied, or just stop after the first level. While this temporarily works, I don't necessarily want to change the owner unless I have to. There are folders that need fixing nested with folders that don't need fixing, I preferably want to keep the current ownership information and permissions as intact as possible.

Next problem comes from the `icacls` command where the permissions are set on each object. Running it on the example above gives me a duplicate permissions entry on `Subfolder`, one inherited Full Control from `Folder` and one explicit Full Control directly on `Subfolder`. While it still achieves what I want, I assume this makes it very much not optimised. I'd prefer to only have one permission on the topmost folder and have that propagate through all subfolders and files. I tried to use (I)F as permission but that gives me 'Invalid parameter' error.

I don't want to take ownership where I don't need to, but I also don't want to rerun the commands on the same toplevel folder after each ownership update. Is there a way to add Full Control permissions for an admin group on a top-level folder and have that permission propagate down through the folder tree without having duplicated explicit/inherited permissions, without having to rerun the code several times, and without taking ownership unless I absolutely have to?

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions on the parent folder only and using `icacls ""$Folder\*"" /q /c /t /reset` to inherit the changes?

Comment: This is just an example, but its highly customisable, have you tried like this:
`$BaseACL = Get-Acl "PATH TO ROOT FOLDER HERE" ; 
$Group = Get-LocalGroup -SID "S-1-5-32-544" ;
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Group,'FullControl','ContainerInherit','ObjectInherit','None','Allow') ;
$BaseACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule) ;
$BaseACL | Set-Acl "PATH TO ROOT FOLDER HERE"`

Comment: @Re1ter That solves the double permission issue but it also removes all explicit permissions, and there are several folders that should have explicit permissions due to sharing between departments, I can't do that.

Comment: @KG-DROID Get-Acl does not work if you don't already have read permissions permission. The problem is that there are many folders where no admin account has any permission at all. While Get-Acl and Set-Acl provides an API solution, they also take much much longer time than icacls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found that all my issue were coming from the fact that the process itself was not properly elevated even though Powershell was running as an admin. I found [this blog post](https://kojiroh.wordpress.com/2020/12/15/how-to-enable-sebackupprivilege-and-serestoreprivilege/) that led me to [this Lee Holmes blog post from 2010](https://www.leeholmes.com/adjusting-token-privileges-in-powershell/) about elevating privileges using `Set-TokenPrivilege`. From there, it became clear that using `Set-Acl` was the preferred option since it's native to Powershell. Here's an example of the final code that works. Before running this I elevate the prompt to have `SeBackupPrivilege`, `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`, and `SeRestorePrivilege`:

```
function Set-MyPermissions {
    param(
        [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity]$Acl,
        [string]$Path
    )

    $PermissionObject = "$env:USERDOMAIN\Domain Admins",
    [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights[]]"FullControl",
    [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit",
    [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None",
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"

    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($PermissionObject)
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
    Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $Acl
    return $Acl
}

function Set-MyOwner {
    param(
        [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity]$Acl,
        [string]$Path,
        [string]$Owner
    )
    
    $OwnerObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Owner)
    $Acl.SetOwner($OwnerObject)
    Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $Acl
    return $Acl
}

foreach ( $Folder in $FoldersToFix ) {
    try {
        $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to read Acl on path $Folder"
        continue
    }
    try {
        $NewAcl = Set-MyPermissions -Path $Folder -Acl $Acl
    }
    catch {
        $OriginalOwner = $Acl.Owner
        try {
            $NewAcl = Set-MyOwner -Path $Folder -Acl $Acl -Owner "Builtin\Administrators"
        }
        catch {
            throw "Failed to update owner on target path $Folder"
        }
        try {
            $NewAcl = Set-MyPermissions -Path $Folder -Acl $NewAcl
        }
        catch {
            throw "Failed to set admin permissions even when owner is Builtin\Administrators"
        }
        try {
            $RestoredAcl = Set-MyOwner -Path $Folder -Acl $NewAcl -Owner $OriginalOwner
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to restore original owner ($OriginalOwner)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I suggest that you recursively traverse all folders, changing permissions only at the current nesting level, for example like this:

```
$start_folder = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test"

Function Change_Permission {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($root_folder)

    $Permission = "(OI)(CI)F"
    $Username = "Domain Admins"
    $GrantString = $Username + ":" + $Permission

    $list_folders = (Get-ChildItem $root_folder -Directory).FullName
    if ($list_folders -eq $null) {
        return
    }
    foreach ($folder in $list_folders) {
        icacls ""$folder"" /C /Q /grant ""$GrantString""
        Change_Permission $folder
    }
    return
}

Change_Permission $start_folder
```

Please note that I'm not using **/T** key in **icacls**

Comment: I will give this a go in my sandbox in a bit, I will get back to you!

Comment: The problem with this one is that Get-ChildItem will fail when you don't already have permission, it's a bit of a catch 22 that you need permission in order to add permissions. I think I'm on to a separate solution that might solve the problem, I can elevate my privilege and use the backup flag to force my way past the problems, but I think it might set off some serious security concerns in the NOC.